# Generic Implementation of MappingSqlQuery in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc

Currently, when we use MappingSqlQuery to get the resultset from DB, we do something like below:

[Extends MappingSqlQuery](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/ExtendsMappingSqlQuery.htm)

In the above example, we have a class LastNameAndAgeQuery extends from MappingSqlQuery, and we applied mapRow method. However, if I want to make some changes in query, let's say I want to add one more info of employee, their birthday. In this way, I have to add:

```
employee.setBirthday(resultSet.getInt("birthday"));
```

in maprow method and in the employee class, I have to add field Birthday and write set and get method.

Is there a generic implementation that if I want to modify query, all I need to do is modify query itself, I don't need to change the maprow method, and add field in employee class. Or a better way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's absurd to modify the query but avoid adding a member field that could hold the new column's value in the POJO. Think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at ORM (Object Relational Mapping) solution such as Hibernate or JPA (Java Persistence API). Typically using ORM you only need to manipulate the POJO (Plain Old Java Object) that represents your table row, and the ORM API will translate that into SQL

Answer (score 1):

The only way if you want to continue to keep `jdbcTemplate` is to go in for generic row mappers like use a map or use the `queryForMap` api's, so you can modify the query to have more columns and access the map to read its content.

But do keep in mind that concrete row mappers increase readability and easy to maintain.